# Functions of 3 position toggle switch on central vac with power head

Tags: switch, central-vacuum

I am trying to find out what should happen when each of the three positions of the rocker toggle switch are selected on my central so called "gas pump" handle of my central vacuum unit equipped with a power head. When the left toggle is in the down position ONLY the power head works, in the center position nothing works, with the right toggle down ONLY the central vacuum works (draws).  Surely the power head and vacuum should come on together. I expect to hear the toggle switch is defective.  The toggle switch looks identical to the one in [this previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/104477/53243).

Comment: On some beam models is off, motor, motor and brush.  Other models the center is off, “forward” position is brush and suction and “back” is suction only.  The switches are OEM and I searched for months.  I finally let a beam dealer replace, and they replaced the entire hose handle.   It’s a 2-pole switch, double throw switch but nothing you can order fits the handle.

Comment: Tyson, I believe you have the answer.  You state you have suction on both settings with the middle one nothing.  I lack suction when the power head is running.  From this I believe I have a defective toggle switch.

Comment: If your switch looks like [this one](http://www.vacuumstore.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=38348-2&Store_Code=VAC-STORE&campaign=Shopping&c=2390606286&matchtype=&keyword=&network=g&placement=&rand=16071800926961213858&adpos=1o3&telnum=8554273582&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIiOXTuNHe2wIVBpFpCh30FArNEAQYAyABEgK-zPD_BwE$, replacement is easy.  Some of the other versions tho you can’t buy the switch.

Comment: If not that switch, the replace the whole handle: https://qualityhomesystems.com/product-details/beam-total-control-handle/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI0s7RrdLe2wIVAS5pCh045QuJEAQYDiABEgKf3PD_BwE